# Virtual Server - php 5.4 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

i have an virtual server with a preinstalled php version 5.3. 
With this version of php my website works correctly. Now i have compiled a new php version 5.4 as cgi application. If i change my domain to the new php version i will get following error in the frontend:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Trace:
#0 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

I have shorten the directory pathes.

I know this is a connection error to my database. But for me it doesn´t make any sense. In a subfolder i have also a typo3 installed. With typo3 i don´t have any problems regarding the database connection.

Is this error known by anyone of you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last few days I have searched the internet after this problem. And now i found the solution.

My hostname in local.xml was "localhost". 
After changing my php version to 5.4 "localhost" was no longer accepted. 
I changed it several times to 127.0.0.1. But no effect. Same error in frontend.

I couldn´t believe this behavior and renamed my var directoy to var_old
After that my connection works correctly. Means i had only caching problem.